# Equivalent of DataOutputStream and DataInputStream in C

Tags: java, c, sockets, datainputstream, dataoutputstream

I wrote this code in java

```
public class Client
{
    private static int    _port;
    private static Socket _socket;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            _port   = 8071;
            _socket = new Socket("localhost", _port);


            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeInt(n);
                dos.flush();



            // Show the server response
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
            int ServerNumber= din.readInt();

            System.out.println(ServerNumber);
            String serverRandomString=din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(serverRandomString);


            din.close();
            dos.close();
        }
```

it's a simple socket communication. My server is in java, but i want to try writing a client in C. There are an alternative to DataOutputStream and DataInputStream in C ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no, not really. Sockets require much more effort in C than in most modern languages. Unfortunately there is no "standard" socket library available [if you're writing a cross platform app you have to compensate between the differences too], and the ones that are available aren't as straight forward as socket programming in java. You'll have to start from the ground up, there are plenty of c/c++ socket tutorials on the web though. You may even find a good third-party library that will help make it easier. Not trying to discourage you here, it's not THAT hard to figure out, it's just remarkably easier to do in Java.

Comment: yeh you're just going to have to learn how to use sockets with C [winsock if you're in windows]. honestly it's good practice